# Evaluate Normal distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution

I want to compute the normal distribution in Matlab but I'm getting different results for my own implementation and the cdf function.

My own implementation is as follows:

```
function prob_density = normal_dist(x, mu, variance)
    prob_density = (1/sqrt(2*pi*variance)) * exp((-(x-mu).^2)/(2*variance));
end
```

Let's assume x = 71.5, mu = 73, sigma = 6.2

When I compute `normal_dist(x,mu,sigma^2)` I'm getting a result of 0.0624896575937. When I compute `cdf('Normal', x, mu, sigma)` I'm getting a result of 0.404415077282744.

Where is the failure?

Comment: Your function is calculating the normal probability density function and the 'cdf()' function calculates the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which one should I use for Gaussian Naive Bayes?

Comment: You should check a reference or post on a statistics site.